# e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("id") / e.targe.getAttribute("id") unit test jest enzyem

Tags: reactjs, testing, events, jestjs, enzyme

Does anyone have a jest/enzyme test example for event.target.getAttribute?

```
    handleButtonsClicks = () => {
      if(e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("id")=== "id1") {
        //
      } else if (e.target.getAttribute("id") === "id2") {
        //
      }
    }
```

```
    <Button id="id1" onClick={handleButtonsClicks}/>
    <Button id="id2" onClick={handleButtonsClicks}/>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing with whatever it is you've already tried? Can you share something you've tried and what about it is not working?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I couldn't simulate properly the path to simulate the click of getAttribute and didn't not receive different results according to the different ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a completed demo:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleButtonsClicks = this.handleButtonsClicks.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonsClicks(e) {
    if (e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('id') === 'id1') {
      console.log('do something');
    } else if (e.target.getAttribute('id') === 'id2') {
      console.log('do another thing');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="id1" onClick={this.handleButtonsClicks}>
          Button 1
        </button>
        <button id="id2" onClick={this.handleButtonsClicks}>
          Button 2
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import SomeComponent from './';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent></SomeComponent>);
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should handle button click', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    expect(wrapper.find('button')).toHaveLength(2);
    const mEvent = { target: { parentNode: { getAttribute: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('id1') } } };
    wrapper.find('#id1').simulate('click', mEvent);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('do something');
    expect(mEvent.target.parentNode.getAttribute).toBeCalledWith('id');
  });

  test('should handle button click', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    expect(wrapper.find('button')).toHaveLength(2);
    const mEvent = {
      target: {
        getAttribute: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('id2'),
        parentNode: { getAttribute: jest.fn() }
      }
    };
    wrapper.find('#id1').simulate('click', mEvent);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('do another thing');
    expect(mEvent.target.getAttribute).toBeCalledWith('id');
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58457004/index.spec.tsx
  SomeComponent
    ✓ should handle button click (16ms)
    ✓ should handle button click (3ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    do something

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    do another thing

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |    83.33 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |    83.33 |      100 |      100 |                12 |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.139s, estimated 8s
```

Comment: I see your answer now - thanks a bunch and marking as solved